# How to make table view cells with div with equal spacing?

Tags: html, css

I want to implement a table using `div` tags. I want cells space always be equal. but in some screen sizes it is not. for instance 4 is not fit in the first line so it is shown in the second line.
I set the `text-align` to `left`. that why we have the extra space in right.

```
1  2  3 --  
4  5  6 --
```

"--" are extra space in right side.
If I set the text-align to center this problem will be resolved but when I have 4 elements, this will be happen:

```
1  2  3
   4
```

In above example spcing is ok but 4 is in the middle and I don't want this.

What I want is this:

```
1  2  3
4
```

***What I want:***

> space between 1 to its left = space between 3 to its right  space 
>   between 2 and 1 = space between 2 and 3

Code:

```
<style>
body {
    font-family: IRANSansMobileFaNum;font-size: medium;
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    color: gray;
    text-align: center;
}

.divTable{
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 10px;
    text-align: left;

    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;

}

.divTableCell {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 4px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 60px;
    font-size: 11px;
    max-width: 120px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img {
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    margin: 4px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='divTable'>
        <div class='divTableBody'>
            <div class='divTableRow'>
                <div class='divTableCell'><img src='1.png' />
                    <br />1</div>
                <div class='divTableCell'><img src='2.png' />
                    <br /> 2</div>
                <div class='divTableCell'><img src='3.png' />
                    <br />3</div>
                <div class='divTableCell'><img src='4.png' />
                    <br />4</div>

                <div class='divTableCell'><img src='5.png' />
                    <br /> 2</div>
                <div class='divTableCell'><img src='6.png' />
                    <br />3</div>
                <div class='divTableCell'><img src='7.png' />
                    <br />4</div>

            </div>

        </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What kind of result that you want?

Comment: @AlvinTheodora I want to have equal spaces between all cells that are in a line. and when a line is not fill with cells, I want that cell positioned to left

Comment: Note that `<img>` and `<br`> do not use and browsers ignore a closing slash in HTML.

Comment: If this is a table of tabular data, you should use `<table>`. If this is a grid, you should use `grid` or, possibly, `flex`. `<div>` doesn't make sense here.